# Increment JSON Data Array by One

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, wordpress, for-loop

[image]I'm wondering why this i+=1 doesn't increment the array by 1. When I click on the button the entire array length is shown. Can someone advise me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to load JSON data from WP related to posts with a certain category. This category I'm loading (http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/photos?categories=12) has 2 posts total. When I console.log postsData.length, I get the value of 2. When I console log postsData I receive Object, Object Object, Object. These posts both load at the same time when the button is clicked, but I want the posts or each object to load 1 at a time. Below is the code:

```
var portfolioPostsBtn = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-btn");
var portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");

if (portfolioPostsBtn){
portfolioPostsBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/photos?categories=12');
      ourRequest.onload = function() {
        if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
          var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
          //console.log(data);
          createHTML(data);

        } else {
          console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
        }
      };

      ourRequest.onerror = function() {
        console.log("Connection error");
};

ourRequest.send();

});
}

function createHTML(postsData){
  var ourHTMLString = '';
// This for loop doesn't increment by 1
  for (var i=0; i<postsData.length; i += 1){
    console.log(postsData.length);
    ourHTMLString += '<h2>' + postsData[i].title.rendered + '</h2>';
    ourHTMLString += '<img class="gallery-test" src="' +postsData[i].acf.image + '"">'
  }
  portfolioPostsContainer.innerHTML = ourHTMLString;
}
```

Comment: Please console.log the `postsData` argument. Add it to your question. You can check if it is in fact an array with `Array.isArray(postsData)`

Comment: Hello Abraham I console log `Array.isArray(postsData)` and receive true back. I added the other info to question.

Comment: array.length is not 0 indexed. if it says 1, it is 1. Can you log the response text before parsing it?

Comment: I get the value of 2 I just double checked

Comment: I just ran your code in my console, it did increase by 1.

Comment: I see that every time I click on the button in the console it increments. The problem is that it initially shows both objects and increments the same way

Comment: Can you clarify what you are expecting to happen and what is happening? How many times does `console.log(postsData.length);` log to the console? If it logs 2 values, your loop is working.

Comment: I added a picture of console.log(postsData) to help clarify. It cycles through the whole loop twice to print both objects. However, every time I click the button I only want one object to show until the array is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me try to understand your question correctly. if you're trying to just display one single post per click. here's what i think you may try:

```js
let portfolioPostsBtn = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-btn");
let portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");

// keep the payload to avoid unnecessary data requests
let postsData = [];

// using this to track click history to display the next post
let counter = 0;

/** not needed for disabling the button **/
// cycle (postsData.length) one by one starting at index 0
// for ex, if there are 3 posts, it would do 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, to eons
// const incrementCounter = () => {
// counter = (counter + 1)%(postsData.length)
// };

// create post html if there is postsData
postsData.length && createHTML();

if (portfolioPostsBtn && !postsData.length){
portfolioPostsBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      let ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/photos?categories=12');
      ourRequest.onload = function() {
        if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
          let data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
          //console.log(data);
          postsData = data;
          createHTML();

        } else {
          console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
        }
      };

      ourRequest.onerror = function() {
        console.log("Connection error");
};

ourRequest.send();

});
}


function disableButton () {
  // this would only work if portfolio-posts-btn is an actual button,
  // otherwise, you'll need to disable the listener and show the
  // user the btn is disabled somehow
  portfolioPostsBtn.setAttribute('disable', true);
}

function createHTML() {
  const strTemplate = `
    <h2>${postsData[counter].title.rendered}</h2>
    <img class="gallery-test" src="${postsData[counter].acf.image}">`;
  // append to the added posts
  portfolioPostsContainer.innerHTML += strTemplate;
  counter++;
  postsData.length === counter && disableButton();
}
```

Comment: _"var is a global variable"_  that is incorrect. Using `const` would also result in an error

Comment: just read your comment about wanting to display the objects one at a time. to do this, you'll need to 

let payload = [], counter = 0;

1. store the postsData payload in an array
2. create html template with postsData[counter]
3. add one to the counter
4. have a check from the btn click to see if payload.length is true, if so, dont fetch again, just create the html template

Comment: @Phil var is a globally scoped variable in Javascript, but yes const would in a for loop since it increments i, however, let would not.

Comment: the article below and tons others have pointed out the difference between using var and let inside of a for loop --- https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744

Comment: I never mentioned anything about using `var` vs `let`. What I'm pointing out is that your statement _"var is a global variable"_ is incorrect. I was also incorrect in saying _"`var` has block scope"_, it has closure scope.

Comment: i feel like we're just going at it on semantics here. pls provide some insights to questions asked on this post

Comment: Hello @ user3366943, can you provide a template of what storing the postsData in a payload would look like?

Comment: i updated my original answer to your request to display one post at a time.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out and it works on the first click but not on the second, the second post doesn't show

Comment: When I console.log(counter) it logs "0" on the second click too

Comment: hum... okay, let's figure this out together. pls console log the counter after incrementCounter() inside the createHTML function, console log counter inside the incrementCounter function at the end after the assignment.  if you're not seeing the counter increase by 1 per click from the console log inside createHTML, the increment function is not working. if you're not seeing the counter increment inside the increment function itself, check to see if postsData.length is what you exact. i also dont know exact shape of the payload to be sure. pls provide on your response to troubleshoot  further.

Comment: Hello @user3366943 thanks for your patience. It's this part right here `counter = (counter + 1)%(postsData.length - 1)` because when I change it to `counter = (counter +=1)%(postsData.length )` I see both images. However the index starts at one rather than 0. But if I add -1 at the end of length it doesn't work. Any reason that might be?

Comment: my mistake, i updated the code in my answer. say if the length of the array is 2. the first func call would do (0 + 1)%2 = 1, the next will do (1 + 1)%2 = 0, so on and so forth

Comment: Oh that makes sense so it's normal for counters to end in 0. I also have one more question: Would it be possible to append each counter using the append method?

Comment: Eliz, have i answered your questions on this post? wanted to make sure the code i provided works for you.  append is a method for working with a HTML node. the counter we have here is a number.  there are methods you can use for a number, take a quick look on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: What I was hoping for was that every time you click on the button it would show the next image and append it. That way all images are eventually displayed. I'll take a look at the article. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: @Elizabeth i made the changes to address your concerns. however i do feel that we seem to be chasing after a moving target. or at least the question you asked originally wasnt about displaying n number posts from a fetch then append each one into a div one at a time. it would be great when you ask the next question on stackoverflow, have a concrete set of criteria written out so we may properly address your concerns the first time around. just my 2cents. :)

Comment: Thank you! It works great and the answer was a lot simpler than I thought. I appreciate your feedback as I'm also trying to improve my questions